# Reading all rows by using multiple columns in java jackcess

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

In Java using Jackcess, I have 2 questions on the below code.

1. In the below code, I have used only the column Active to fetch rows.
   How can I add multiple columns in same table? Or can I make a join?
2. The below code fetches only 1 row. Where can I find the logic of
   reading the entire result set?

The docs of jackcess is not complete on these aspects. Also in making search, all examples were related to jackcess 1 and not for latest version.

```
Row row = CursorBuilder.findRow(tblTC, Collections.singletonMap("Active", true));

if(row != null) {
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

Comment: For more complex queries (including JOINs, etc.) you might want to consider using `UCanAccess`. For more information look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Comment: Wow. That was super easy. Can you please add this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more complex queries (including JOINs, etc.) you might want to consider using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html). For more information see a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).